# php - regex hostname extraction

Tags: php, regex, expression, hostname

I have been looking around for a regex expression that will spit out just the 'stackoverflow' part and no www. or .com etc. All I could find was to check if the url's were valid... I have used php's url filter to determine that much I now am looking to determine which site it is.

I have never written an expression before so I am hoping someone can check it/recommend a better solution.

```
preg_match('@^(?:http://)(?:www.)?([^.]+)@i', $url, $matches)
```

edit:
All the url's I am dealing with are .com if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one-liner without using regular expressions!!!

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$d = array_shift( explode( '.', str_replace('www.', '', parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST )) ) );
echo $d;
```

Comment: haha... its only a one liner because you stuck it all in one line :) Regardless it works well. Its the best so far.

Comment: This fails. Use this string `www.myusualhost-test.co.in.php53-1.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com` and it gives me `myusualhost-test` whereas I just want `myusualhost-test.co.in.php53-1.dfw1-2.websitetestlink`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered PHP's [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function?

Comment: the function is really great.... except it still leaves me with sometimes being 'www.' and sometimes no 'www.' so I will still have to preg_replace the www.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the thing you're having is a URL and the domain end in .com a simple thing like

```
preg_match('#([^\.]*)\.com#', $url, $matches);
```

should do the trick.

While this will fail on a domain like `www.com.foo.com` but might be enough, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('#https?://(?:www.)?(.*?)\.com#i', $str, $match);
```