# Finding part of a string that a user has sent via POST

Tags: php, url, post, switch-statement

My users can send links from popular file hosts like Rapidshare, Megaupload, Hotfile and FileFactory. I need to somehow find out what filehost they sent the link from and use the correct class for it appropriately.

For example, if I sent a Rapidshare link in a form on my web page, I need to somehow cycle through each file host that I allow until I find the text `rapidshare.com`, then I know the user has posted a Rapidshare link.

Perhaps a PHP example:

```
switch($_POST['link'])
{
    case strstr($_POST['link'], 'rapidshare.com'):
        // the link is a Rapidshare one
        break;

    case strstr($_POST['link'], 'megaupload.com'):
        // the link is a Megaupload one
        break;

    case strstr($_POST['link'], 'hotfile.com'):
        // the link is a Hotfile one
        break;

    case strstr($_POST['link'], 'filefactory.com'):
        // the link is a Filefactory one
        break;
}
```

However, I know for a fact this isn't correct and I'd rather not use a huge IF statement if I can help it.

Does anyone have any solution to this problem?

If you need me to explain more I can try, English isn't my native language so it's kinda hard.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind guys, I used this:

```
$sentLink = trim($_POST['link']);

$host = parse_url($sentLink, PHP_URL_HOST);

switch($host)
{
    case 'rapidshare.com':
        echo "RS";
        break;
    case 'megaupload.com':
        echo "MU";
        break;
    case 'hotfile.com':
        echo "HF";
        break;
    case 'filefactory.com':
        echo "FF";
        break;
    default:
        echo "WTF! D:";
}
```

First time I've heard of `parse_url` :)

Comment: See my post about making sure to parse out the www. that can be returned from parse_url.

Answer (score 1):

According to [php - regex hostname extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813599/php-regex-hostname-extraction) you want to make sure you check for the www. portion of th eurl as parse_url can sometimes return that as well.

```
$sentLink = trim($_POST['link']);

$host = array_shift( explode( '.', str_replace('www.', '', parse_url( $sentLink , PHP_URL_HOST )) ) );

switch($host)
{
    case 'rapidshare.com':
        echo "RS";
        break;
    case 'megaupload.com':
        echo "MU";
        break;
    case 'hotfile.com':
        echo "HF";
        break;
    case 'filefactory.com':
        echo "FF";
        break;
    default:
        echo "WTF! D:";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about the www part :)